# Unable to set textbox value through $scope using angular UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-ui-grid

```
 <div data-ng-controller="OfficeController" class="container">


    <div class="row col-md-12" style="margin:10px;">
        <form name="Office">
            <div class="col-sm-12">


                <label for="Name" class="form-group col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-group col-xs-6" id="Name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="Name" required />
                </div>


                <label for="Org_ID" class="form-group col-sm-2 control-label">Org_ID</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-group col-xs-6" id="Org_ID" placeholder="Org_ID" ng-model="Org_ID" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
    </div>
```

i have two textboxes in view
adding button to uigrid column for get row data and call get

```
   $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'Offices',
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'OFFICE_ID', displayName: 'OFFICE_ID' },
      { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name' },
      { field: 'Org_ID', displayName: 'Org_ID' },
               {
                   name: 'ShowScope',
                   cellTemplate: '<button class="btn primary" ng-click="grid.appScope.get(row)">Click Me</button>'
               }
    ],
    filterOptions: { filterText: '', useExternalFilter: false },
    showFilter: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    showGridFooter: true,
};
```

alert(res.Name) shows me correct name but i am unable to set textbox name value??

```
 $scope.get = function (row) {
    alert(row.entity.OFFICE_ID);
    var promiseGetSingle = OfficeService.get(row.entity.OFFICE_ID);
    promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
        var res = pl.data;
        alert(res.Name);
        $scope.OFFICE_ID = res.OFFICE_ID;
        $scope.Org_ID = res.Org_ID;
        $scope.Name = res.Name;
        $scope.IsNewRecord = 0;
    },
              function (errorPl) {
                  console.log('failure loading Organization', errorPl);
              });
}
```

Any idea how to set textbox value through scope,ir any method, what i want is when users click on row button i want to poulate fields by getting data from that particular row...in UI Grid Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Please try as shown below.

```
 $scope.Name='';//define the variable globally

 $scope.get = function (row) {
    var promiseGetSingle = OfficeService.get(row.entity.OFFICE_ID);
    promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
        $scope.Name = res.Name;
   },
 }
```